# How to type `K extends keyof T` when T can be undefined?

Tags: typescript

I want to add TypeScript types to this JS function:

```js
function getProp(obj, prop) {
  if (!obj) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return obj[prop];
}
```

If there was no requirement to handle `undefined`, this would work:

```
function getProp<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: P): T[P] {
  // ...
}
```

However, with `undefined`, this naive approach with `| undefined` doesn't work:

```
function getProp<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T | undefined, prop: P): T[P] | undefined {
  if (!obj) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return obj[prop];
}

const obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'obj1',
};
const obj2 = undefined;

getProp(obj1, 'id');
getProp(obj2, 'id');
              ^^^ Argument of type '"id"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=21#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AcA8AKgDSIaKoAeUqYAJgM6IDWqAnnMIoQHwAUcAEYArAFzdEAH0Tg6qYDDCo6pXDlziMASnGEA2hgC6UmfXmLliAN4AoRIhhc%20AQiHCt1u-cRZ0ILEiy5kp0ANxeAL42Xr5Q-khuemp4huFRNhAIDFCIbgCMiAC8nvYwdOJ5xF5gAIYAtqjiAOT5TVUR4Zlg2bkiAExFpnIKIeE2aJjqAiKViE1lTVrhE9h408J9pPN0i6FAA).

What's the best way to type this?

Comment: Do you want `getProp(obj2, "randomKey")` to succeed but you still want `getProp(obj1, "randomKey")` to fail?  I'm a little unclear on the use case.  You could likely type the call signature like `function getProp<T, P extends (undefined extends T ? keyof any : keyof T)>(obj: T, prop: P): (P extends keyof T ? T[P] : undefined);` but that's complicated so I'd like to understand what your intent is before I suggest that as an answer.

Comment: My use case is to call `getProp(items.find(i => i.id === 3), 'name')`, have 'name' be checked by TypeScript but the `getProp` function should also handle `undefined` that can be returned by `Array#find`.

Comment: For example, `R.prop(R.find(R.propEq('id', 3)), items)` in Ramda is very close to my example. Their typings are not correct either (they don't handle `undefined`) so I'm wondering how to do it in "plain" `getProp` function.

Comment: So your use case is not to use `getProp(undefined, "randomKey")`.  Note that your "naive" approach [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AcA8AKgDSIaKoAeUqYAJgM6IDWqAnnMIoQHwAUcAEYArAFzdEAH0Tg6qYDDCo6pXDlziMASnGEA2hgC6UmfXmLliAN4AoRPcQwufAIRDhW63Yc+s6EFhIsuZKdADc3vYAvjaRiH5QAUjuemp4hhExEAgMUIjuAIyIALxePjB04gXEcWAAhgC2qOIA5IUtNVER2WC5jjQNTKV6hRk2aJjqfDADDAB0CvTTJTyOcxUlxaUFWqQARBV7WmGIAPSniGAgDYKoWCbBi8o2QA) with the `getProp(items.find...)` example you just posted.  What's the problem?

Comment: That's a very good question :) I probably confused myself – had some typing issues with Ramda, tried to simplify it to a plain example which... works. Sorry about that and thanks for your help, @jcalz!

Comment: @jcalz Do you still want to post your example as an answer? I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thnk if I were going to try to go all out and make the `getProp()` function accept all kinds of `obj` parameters and then allow any key if `obj` might be `undefined`, I'd do something like this:

```
function getProp<T,
    P extends T extends any ? (undefined extends T ? keyof any : keyof T) : never
>(
    obj: T,
    prop: P
): T extends any ? (P extends keyof T ? T[P] : undefined) : never;
function getProp<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T | undefined, prop: P): T[P] | undefined {
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") {
        return undefined;
    }

    return obj[prop];
}
```

That's super complicated but it has some possibly desirable behavior:

```
const obj1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'obj1',
};
const obj2 = undefined;
const items = [obj1];

getProp(items.find(i => i.id === 1), "id"); // number | undefined
getProp(obj1, "id"); // number
getProp(obj2, "who knows"); // undefined
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { a: "b" }, "a"); // string | number
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 1 }, "z"); // error! "z" not "a" | "b"
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 1 }, "a"); // number | undefined
```

But for the use case as you described, you're only interested in passing in `undefined` to the extent that `obj` might be `T | undefined` for some particular `T`, and you never plan to actually call `getProp(undefined, "something")`.  In which case, your "naive" approach works well enough:

```
function getProp<T, P extends keyof T>(obj: T | undefined, prop: P): T[P] | undefined {
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") {
        return undefined;
    }

    return obj[prop];
}
```

Observe:

```
getProp(items.find(i => i.id === 1), "id"); // number | undefined
getProp(obj1, "id"); // number | undefined
getProp(obj2, "who knows"); // error!
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { a: "b" }, "a"); // string | number | undefined
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 1 }, "z"); // error! "z" not "a" | "b"
getProp(Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 1 }, "a"); // number | undefined
```

Possibly the only thing "bad" about this is that all the outputs of `getProp()` include `undefined` in their type, even when you are calling `getProp(obj, "id")`, a known-defined `obj` with a known-present `"id"`.  But that seemed to be what you wanted, so there you go.  You basically answered your own question!

So, uh, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhATiAXgTyQbwCglikAzAV2HgBcBLAe2CQHMJqAFNemAHgBUANERIj2SCAA9qEYABMoSPuKkz5SEMFwB+JAApKsiKVrAIs5dLkKlOgNYRs9Uus1IAXEnuPnfAJTukUwA3CDRhYgA+XXCRJHoAIwArD0EYkRguGA92GN8Ui1UFDW09MUlLNS8nRSQdPgBtdgBdAIMjEzN-D2DQgG4Yiio6RhY2Tm5+ASQylStPB2q+KITkmoAfJDbjU1kpjO5svMVGlo2tjvNCWJJaZ11qbBgIapWkAF4PpAAic52v-yu11iaDY5DQTF+Zn6QKQAF8CGkSCDqGCmCt6vsYE1oSR4TF4IwoNQ4kkAIzvfCI4i0WQeUlCGGgSAeADkK1JLIZuJxxAJwCJJMSACYKZDZDykHyBbRpGAFG8kPV2diESJWBxMroZRA5QA6bayLXvCJIWi6mnvT6k3xTL40-69JAAeidgXIYHioSQZzk7R2MXV4xgunZtvtvkdLrdHtCAbGmpWQttAHcABb0TzAejJqAO52usVxjXcXQAWRA1FTuowcnoYF0-h4SAADLqAKy1fDqOlwgJ4bvfeJfOG2kB5qNEtAmZje6OesJq+Ml8uV6saWR1htIJutjs6fsgHuwvtIeJH22Yceu0JcNAAQm+l8C9GJXzHs6+Q6LQbLFarNY3etGxbdtOwPI8TzPJByVhUcrznL0fUMbYzARAg8SZaA4EQJAADEOkpERBhoBgmEDTJJmmAo5iqHxliSfIkL9Mw9kyQ4UhOWcxUIoFbj0B4nheJJLQVH5fRQ2R-h4mFiGRVFNnEi4JREPEYTk8FBQxTIVRU1USClYl2QpQFrhpOkuWuTDWXZTkYlhCUDMFEUFTFBzCWJbU5QpJUyRVb9NU8qB9RMQ1aGNU1zXMD4FWtMNJIjfMELQLjFP9Rdi2DUNvnDSNXWAd15xS5CLn8ktExTdNM2zXMEqjG96HvUrgxXf9103YDdzAgcYJPQ9B2HWDvjHWrXUnadZ3ymNkqYiSmt-VcAPa7cQL3Ls+p6jx+ygmCL3g+r70fYcs1fd8Nk-L45patdayA5bOv3bre0209zyG+DJsKmaSthIA)

Comment: That's an _awesome_ answer to an (almost) non-question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
function getProp<O, P extends O extends undefined ? any : keyof O>(obj: O, prop: P)  {
  if (!obj) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return obj[prop];
}

const obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'obj1',
};
const obj2 = undefined;

getProp(obj1, 'id');
getProp(obj2, 'id');
```

So if the first param is undefined I set second type as `any`. I don't type return as it is nicely inferred. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AcA8A8gDSIaKoAeUqYAJgM6KEXW2OLh2rAxip1EAfkQBDMAE9EALkQBrVBLjBmAPgAUcAEYArWSUS4cuWRgCUiRAG8AsAChLMFeoCE2nRdsPLiLOhBYSFw8fAIA3PaWAL72kb7%20gYjuANpGeAC6EXYxdvYQCAxQSboAjIgAvNZxMHSyJcRxYKIAtqiyAOTuJe0N2Vn5YIXFOgBMFZz0Ifx0WfZomMaapaTtNe1mWfPYeEujK2sb9kA)

Comment: Ah, `any` does the trick! I was trying with `string` in its place and was getting "Type P cannot be used to index type O" ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AcA8A8gDSIaKoAeUqYAJgM6KEXW2OLh2rAxip1EAfkQMoWPskQAuRAGtUATzjBmAPgAUcAEYArWSUS4cuWRgCUBgNoYAuogA+nejz4DEiAN4AoDzFUaAIQ6uuZevh6IWOggWEhcrvx0ANwRAL7eEdFQsUghVsZ4tqkZ3hAIYoghAIyIALzhfnSy1cQRYACGALaosgDkNX1taanlYJUhAEz1zty8SaneaJgmWnqtiH0wdH3mqcvYeGu6k6RbdJO7yUA)). Thanks!

Comment: I'm... not sure you want `any` in there, as the described use case `getProp([obj1].find(i => i.id === 1), "name");` will return type `unknown` instead of the presumably desired `string | undefined`.

Comment: In the question description there was no such use case